# See Event Logs of other users

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, limits

We're currently blasting through our SFDC daily API limits and I wanted to see who is causing it.

As per the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_download) I went into the Event Log File viewer they offer (salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com) and logged in with my administrator account. However I can only see my own user's activity (login, logout). Is there a way for a admin user to pull that for other users or do I have to get each of them to go in and download the log files?

Comment: Have you tried looking `API Usage last 7 days` standard report? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003706&type=1

Comment: mhm that works but it took some digging as the administrative reports are only accessible in the classic version, not lightning.

Comment: I had raised an idea for it 2 years back :( https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E4FZQA0

Comment: The IdeaExchange URL is moved to https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgVyUAJ/make-standard-salesforce-reports-available-for-lightning-experince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event Log File viewer is a GUI wrapper around the [Event Monitoring API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm). As such, it will only show you the details that are currently being reported by that API. By default you only get the [login, logout, and insecure external asset events for free](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm) in a production org.

That said, the data returned from that API is not specific to the user accessing it.

If you want to get fine grained monitoring of API calls you will want the [API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#api) event type, which is a paid add-on. Also, there isn't currently a single Event Type that will track all API usage. Please consider voting for the idea: [Event Monitoring for all calls that contribute to the 24 hour API request limit](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgVyUAJ/make-standard-salesforce-reports-available-for-lightning-experince)

I've made notes previously about the various ways the the API usage can be monitored - [Monitoring your Salesforce API usage](http://www.fishofprey.com/2016/06/monitoring-your-salesforce-api-usage.html). This includes the **API Usage Last 7 Days** report that Pranay pointed out, the limit headers that get added to REST and SOAP responses, and the dedicated REST limits resource.

Answer (score 1):

In Salesforce classic, we have `API Usage last 7 days` report in `Administrative Reports` folder that gives you count of API calls used  by each user in last 7 days.

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003706&type=1

Comment: Why does this have such drastically different information than the trailhead ELF app? That one list for my admin user the login/logout activity ONLY but the 7 days report shows ~4k API requests per day for my user. Any way to drill down further in the report?

Comment: You might have to raise a case with SF for more details